# ASP.NET MVC workaround for ajax.abort()

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a rest endpoint on asp.net mvc:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<SomeEntity> Get(){
    // Lets imagine that this operation lasts for 1 minute
    var someSlowOperationResult = SomeWhere.GetDataSlow();
    return someSlowOperationResult;
}
```

On the frontEnd I have a next javascript:

```
var promise = $.get("/SomeEntities");
setTimeout(function(){promise.abort()}, 100);
```

How to force `Thread` to die after abort call, to prevent `slow` calculation to be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `Response` have `isClientConnected` property. So we can use next approach:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<SomeEntity> Get(){
        var gotResult = false;
        var result = new List<SomeEntity>();
        var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken ct = tokenSource2.Token;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Do something with cancelation token to break current operation
            result = SomeWhere.GetSomethingReallySlow();
            gotResult = true;
        }, ct);
        while (!gotResult)
        {
            if (!Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                tokenSource2.Cancel();
                return result;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        return result;
}
```

Can we? Or I miss something?

`UPDATE:`

Yes, it works

Comment: Even if we call abort() on the ajax call the client is still connected, so IsClientConnected will return true. It will return false if the client redirects to another page or closes the browser.

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics but how server-side will know that client closed the browser? ;)

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics just tested, you are wrong. It works! If I abort request using promise.abort() I get to the tokenSource2.Cancel() on backend.

Answer (score 0):

The backend has no idea that you have called `abort()` and if the request has already been sent then the server-side logic will run until it completes. In order to stop it from running you will have to send another request to your `controller` which notifies that controller that you've aborted the request and the controller will have to access the instance that is currently running you slow operation and this instance should have a method which forces the calculations to cancel.

Comment: I think that on a lowlevel - abort closes connection between browser and server-side, so there should be the way how to handle it.